# How to update a value an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, isset

I have this variable `$variable = "own=1,contract_start=1";` and I wanna find this variable an array.
Array name is $variables this is my array:

```
Array
(
[own] => Array
    (
        [type] => bool
        [value] => 0
    )

[contr_name] => Array
    (
        [type] => bool
        [value] => 0
    )

[all_votes] => Array
    (
        [type] => int
        [value] => 0
    )

[contract_start] => Array
    (
        [type] => bool
        [value] => 0
    )

[contract_end] => Array
    (
        [type] => bool
        [value] => 0
    )

[T] => Array
    (
        [type] => clock
        [value] => 
    )

[a] => Array
    (
        [type] => int
        [value] => 1
    )

[candi_ID] => Array
    (
        [type] => int
        [value] => 1
    )

[voter_ID] => Array
    (
        [type] => int
        [value] => 1
    )

[] => Array
    (
        [type] => 
        [value] => 
    )

 )
```

if the value is not equal to existing value an array so I wanna update the value with variable value.
This is my code:

```
$variable = "own=1,contract_start=1";
function updateTheValue($variables,$variable) {

    // Split variable looking for into name and value
    $vars = explode(",", $variable);
    $match = false;

    foreach ($vars as $var){
        $expbyequal = explode("=", $var);

        // If this variable is set
        if ( isset($variables [trim($expbyequal[0])]) )  {
            // Compare value with stored value
            if ( $variables [trim($expbyequal[0])]['value'] == trim($expbyequal[1]) ) {
                $match = true;
            }else{

                $variables[trim($expbyequal[0])] = ["value" => trim($expbyequal[1])]);
                $match = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return $match;
}
$testing = updateTheValue($variables,$variable);
```

Any idea will be appreciable.

Comment: You can use in_array function for check in array value exists or not

Comment: Change return $match; to return $variables;

Comment: If you are going to work more in this, may I suggest looking into a more OO concept.  You could define classes for the different data types and this would then make validation of the values a core part of the code (which you don't do any of at the moment).  You could also add more complex types as you develop the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns `$match`, which could be `true` or `false`, it doesn't allows you to see your changes.

```
function updateTheValue(&$variables,$variable) {

    // Split variable looking for into name and value
    $vars = explode(",", $variable);
    $match = false;

    foreach ($vars as $var){
        $expbyequal = explode("=", $var);

        // If this key exists in main keys
        if ( in_array(trim($expbyequal[0]), array_keys($variables)) )  {

            // Compare value with stored value
            if ( $variables [trim($expbyequal[0])]['value'] == trim($expbyequal[1]) ) {
                $match = true; 
            }else{ 
                $variables[trim($expbyequal[0])]["value"] = trim($expbyequal[1]);
                $match = false; 
            }
        }
    }
    return $match;
}

updateTheValue($variables,$variable);

print_r($variables);
```

With this function you will change data value which key exists in the main keys. You don't need to use `$testing` variable, cause reference `&` mutates your main array.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/m8h8C)**

Answer (score 2):

Only a couple of minor changes to the function.

The main problem is that you are only changing the value of the variables in a local copy, you need to change the variables array to be passed by reference to allow it to update the original data.  Adding `&` in front of the parameter `$variables` should do this.

```
function updateTheValue(&$variables,$variable) {
```

Also when you set the value, instead of just updating the value, you are setting the element to a new array with just the value part, so change that line to...

```
$variables[trim($expbyequal[0])]["value"]= trim($expbyequal[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this resolves your answer to the question :)**

```
$variable = "own=1,contract_start=1";
function updateTheValue($variables,$variable) {

    // Split variable looking for into name and value
    $vars = explode(",", $variable);
    $match = false;

    foreach ($vars as $var){
        $expbyequal = explode("=", $var);        

            // If this variable is set
            if (array_key_exists($expbyequal[0],$variables)){

            // Compare value with stored value
            if ( $variables[trim($expbyequal[0])]['value'] == trim($expbyequal[1])) {
                $match = true;
            }else{
                $variables[trim($expbyequal[0])]['value'] = trim($expbyequal[1]);
                $match = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return $variables;
}

$variables = updateTheValue($variables,$variable);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($variables);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have few issues.

First - you need to pass $variables by refence so it will be changed in global scope when you update it inside function.

Second - your $match obviously only will be `true` when the last parameter in  "own=1,contract_start=1" is matched. I believe that is not what you expect. Expectidly you want "at least one parameter match" or "all parameter match" logic here. I use the second one in my example.

```php
<?php

$array = [
    "own" => [
        "type"  => "bool",
        "value" => 0
    ],

    "contr_name" => [
        "type"  => "bool",
        "value" => 0
    ],

    "all_votes" => [
        "type"  => "int",
        "value" => 0
    ],

    "contract_start" => [
        "type"  => "bool",
        "value" => 0
    ],

    "contract_end" => [
        "type"  => "bool",
        "value" => 0
    ],

    "T" => [
        "type"  => "clock",
        "value" => ""
    ],

    "a" => [
        "type"  => "int",
        "value" => 1
    ],

    "candi_ID" => [
        "type"  => "int",
        "value" => 1
    ],

    "voter_ID" => [
        "type"  => "int",
        "value" => 1
    ]
];

/** updateTheValue will return true if every parameter in $variable is
 *   exist in $variables and its values are the same.
 *   &$variables parameters send $variables "by reference"
 */
function updateTheValue(&$variables, $variable)
{
    $everyValueMatch = true;
    $variable = str_replace(",", "&", $variable);
    parse_str($variable, $parameters);

    foreach ($parameters as $parameterName => $parameterValue) {
        if (!isset($variables[$parameterName])) {
            $everyValueMatch = false;
            continue;
        }

        if ($variables[$parameterName]['value'] == $parameterValue) {
            continue;
        }

        $everyValueMatch = false;
        $variables[$parameterName]['value'] = $parameterValue;
    }
    return $everyValueMatch;
}

/** START */

$variable = "own=1,contract_start=1";

updateTheValue($array,$variable);
```

Also, it's more easy to convert `"own=1,contract_start=1"` string to url like string `"own=1&contract_start=1"` and then parse it to array with `parse_str()` function.